# Controlling model creation in Django and DRF

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Consider the following Django model and DRF-based API:

```
class Disk(models.Model):
    size = models.IntegerField(...)
    free_space = models.IntegerField(...)


# ---- Serializers ---- #
class DiskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Disk
        fields = ('free_space', 'size')
        read_only_fields = ('size', )


class CreateDiskSerializer(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        model = Disk
        fields = ('size', )  # note, size only!


# ---- View ---- #   
class DisksView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def get_serializer(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return CreateDiskSerializer
        else:
            return DiskSerializer
```

I am trying to implement the idea of initializing the value of `free_space` field from `size` on model creation.

The naive approach would be overriding `Disk.save()` but that is something I would use at the very last resort. Another approach would be creating a custom model manager which overrides `.create()`, e.g.:

```
class DiskManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, **kwargs):
        if 'free_space' not in kwargs:
            try:
                kwargs['free_space'] = kwargs['size']
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return super().create(**kwargs)
```

Does it look acceptable to you? Is there a better solution?

Comment: create looks better than save.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend overriding the `create` method of `CreateDiskSerializer` to look something like:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    validated_data['free_space'] = validated_data['size']
    return super(CreateDiskSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Comment: I've considered this, and the reason of not overriding `Serializer.create()` is that IMO the Model layer should take care of data integrity. Note, that this could have been written via database triggers (e.g. if the backend is Postgres or Oracle).